$C^*$ algebra and deformation quantization
I heard that (from ref )

Classical observables :  The set of observables $\mathcal{O}$ of a classical systems are exactly the self-adjoint elements of a separable commutative unital $C^*$-algebra.

and

Quantum observable : The set of a quantum systems are exactly the self-adjoint elements of a separable (non-commutative) unital $C^*$ algebra.

In terms of $C^*$ algebra, it seems that distinction between quantum and classical is determined by the non-commutative, commutativeness of algebra.
But in the usual, deformation quantization contexts, after equipped with poisson structure, we deform (physically it might be more relevant to use perturb) the poisson bracket with introduce the quantum parameter $\hbar$.
How this can be appeared in the context of $C^*$ algebra?

I feel like this is a better question to ask on Physics StackExchange. In any case, though, lots of it depend on how exactly you perform the quantization. In some of the literature, the quantization is simply done by changing the Poisson brackets to commutators, which makes it explicit we are getting some non-commutativity. (That is, the canonical commutation relation.)

Also see the “Quantization” section of the Wikipedia article on Poisson bracket: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket
